# Please Wait AlertView while talking to server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How can I show an AlertView while the application communicates to the server via HTTP Post? My current code that I have doesn't work correctly.

Basically, an AlertView comes up asking to confirm something. If confirmed, the following code takes place:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{//this is for when the person clicks OK
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"OK"])
    {
        //do alert
        UIAlertView *waitAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Communicating with Server..."  
                                                            message:nil 
                                                           delegate:nil  
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil  
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];  
        UIActivityIndicatorView *loading = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 50, 30, 30)];
        loading.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
        [waitAlert addSubview:loading];
        [loading startAnimating];
        [waitAlert show];

        //communicate with Server
        RetailTransaction *retailTransaction = [[RetailTransaction alloc]init];
        ServerConnection *serverConnection = [[ServerConnection alloc]init];
        NSData *serverResponse = [serverConnection postData:[retailTransaction xmlToXml:
                                                             note.text:
                                                             pin.text:
                                                             total.text]];
        NSString *serverResponseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:serverResponse
                                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Server Responded with: %@", serverResponseString);
```

There's more code to this method, but this gets the basic stuff across. The `waitAlert` doesn't even come up until after the application has communicated with the server, at which point it only comes up for a split second. Does anyone know why this is happening? It should come up BEFORE communicating with the server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: On a side note, using AlertView for a "Please wait" message is a very bad idea in terms of user experience.

Comment: What would you recommend while waiting for the server to respond?

Comment: Actually a simple message shown somewhere on the screen would be enough. Anything that doesn't make the user dismiss something that's essentially a status message. If you have bottom toolbar, show the message right there, along with the activity indicator view. Some people use an overlay like the one that shows up when you're changing volume on the iPhone or on a Mac. Or just use UIActivityIndicatorView alone. It will be enough of an indication that your app is doing something currently. Of course don't forget to activate the network activity indicator in phone's status bar as well.

Comment: That's what I currently do for the please wait. It gets dismissed on its own without someone clicking any button.

Comment: To the user it communicates: "Hey, something's wrong. You'll have to wait while I connect to a server". This is not an alert-type situation. Can you imagine a message box popping up every time you load a new page in the browser? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this part to another function and run that function in a background thread.

```
        //communicate with Server
    RetailTransaction *retailTransaction = [[RetailTransaction alloc]init];
    ServerConnection *serverConnection = [[ServerConnection alloc]init];
    NSData *serverResponse = [serverConnection postData:[retailTransaction xmlToXml:
                                                         note.text:
                                                         pin.text:
                                                         total.text]];
    NSString *serverResponseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:serverResponse
                                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Server Responded with: %@", serverResponseString);

....
```

The reason why the alertview does not show up before the call is that the main thread gets hung.

Comment: Say you moved it to a function called

`(void)sendRequest;`

Then to run it in the background write:

        `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(sendRequest) withObject:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

```
-(void)sendMessage{
   NSString *url = @"http://www.your-server.com";
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
    [alertView show];
}

-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
     [alertView hide];
}


-(void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
    NSLog(@"%@", [[request error] description]);
}
```

In this case, you'd call [self sendMessage] from where you launch your alert, but I simplified it a bit. The key is to do the request asynchronously.

This example doesn't do a POST, but ASIHTTPRequest is cabable of that too.